# wordpress options categories

Tags: wordpress

Let me start of by saying I am a total noob when it comes to PHP and all the lovely stuff you need to make a real good theme. I got pretty far - mostly thanks to posts here -, but now I am a bit stuck. So here it comes:

I have a index page with multiple loops. Naturally I want to give the user the option to choose which category displays in which loop.

I have found some code already but nothing really that I understand or was able to get to work.
I'd much appreciate a link to a tutorial or a solution here. I am looking of a solution that is code based, in other words i don’t want to use plugins.

thanks!

Comment: Can you add the code you found..?

Comment: not really it was a bunch and I am not even sure it was what i was looking for :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after many more hours of just trying and searching the god of google let me to find this page:

http://www.onedesigns.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-wordpress-theme-options-page

it help me and just about all works now!